# Insert 0 in pandas series for timeseries gaps

Tags: pandas

In order to properly plot data, I need the missing values to be shown as 0. I do not want to have a 0 value for each missing day, as that bloats the storage. How do I insert 0 value for each `type` column for each gap's first and last day?  I do not need 0 inserted before and after the whole sequence.  Bonus: what if timeseries is monthly or weekly data (date set to the first of the month, or to every Monday)

For example, this timeseries contains one gap between 3rd and 10th of January for type `A`. I need to insert a 0 value on the 4th and the 9th of January.

```
df = DataFrame({"date":[datetime(2015,1,1) + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 3)+range(8, 13)+range(2, 9)], "type": ['A']*8+['B']*7, "value": np.random.randint(10, 100, size=15)})

         date type  value
0  2015-01-01    A     97
1  2015-01-02    A     11
2  2015-01-03    A     89  <-- last date before the gap
3  2015-01-09    A     31  <-- first day after the gap
4  2015-01-10    A     64
5  2015-01-11    A     82
6  2015-01-12    A     75
7  2015-01-13    A     24
8  2015-01-03    B     72
9  2015-01-04    B     46
10 2015-01-05    B     26
11 2015-01-06    B     91
12 2015-01-07    B     36
13 2015-01-08    B     53
14 2015-01-09    B     85
```

Desired result (the row indexes would would be different)

```
         date type  value
0  2015-01-01    A     97
1  2015-01-02    A     11
2  2015-01-03    A     89
.  2015-01-03    A     0   <-- gap starts - new value
                           <-- do NOT insert any more values for 04--07
.  2015-01-08    A     0   <-- gap ends - new value
3  2015-01-09    A     31
4  2015-01-10    A     64
5  2015-01-11    A     82
6  2015-01-12    A     75
7  2015-01-13    A     24
8  2015-01-03    B     72
9  2015-01-04    B     46
10 2015-01-05    B     26
11 2015-01-06    B     91
12 2015-01-07    B     36
13 2015-01-08    B     53
14 2015-01-09    B     85
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an inelegant solution, but it seems to be easiest to split the dataframe up, fill in the missing dates, and recombine, like so:

```
# with pandas imported as pd

dfA = df[df.type=='A']
new_axis = pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max())

dfA.set_index('date', inplace=True)
missing_dates = list(set(new_axis).difference(dfA.index))
dfA.loc[min(missing_dates)] = 'A', 0
dfA.loc[max(missing_dates)] = 'A', 0

df = pd.concat([df[df.type=='B'].set_index('date'), dfA])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you create 0s for every missing day, whereas I must have it just for the first and last day of the gap. Otherwise my storage will explode )